# Thunderbird distorts some messages

Tags: thunderbird, ubuntu-mate

Thunderbird is displaying some messages in a distorted view.

The only ones that are distorted are spam.

And when I try to select those as spam, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Please use the "add image" button to add screenshots instead of posting external links as **you have been told before**.

Comment: I made an edit. What is wrong with using an external link? It would use less space on askunbuntu website. ?

Comment: Some people don't like visiting other sites just to view an image. In my case, I either avoid clicking on such links or  do so in private browsing mode.

Comment: Also, from what I understand, Stack Exchange has an arrangement with imgur.com. The images are hosted there and not by AU. Note the `stack` bit in your image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ergn.png

Comment: And where exactly in the image is the distortion?

Comment: The format of subject is not what shows when I read my mail using Yahoo. I did figure how to mark a message as spam. So, the distortion is no longer a big issue.